# I'm trying to do x^3 - y^3 (signed) in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

im using 8086 assembly (tasm)
I want to do simple program that take x^3 - y^3 (x and y are db) and save the answer to another db (and print a massage if the result too big for db to hold)
there is my code:

```
mov al, x ;mov x to al for multiply
    imul x; ax = al*x (=x^2)
    imul x; ax = ax*x (low), dx = ax*x (high) (=x^3)
    mov low_x, ax; save low x^3 (dw)
    mov high_x, dx; save high x^3 (dw)
    mov al, y ;mov y to al for multiply
    imul y; ax = al*y (=y^2)
    imul y; ax = ax*y (low), dx = ax*y (high) (=y^3)
    mov low_y, ax; save low y^3 (dw)
    mov high_y, dx; save high y^3 (dw)
```

now what? how can i sub between the numbers to get the right answer?
thanks!

Comment: BTW the code you have will only work if `x*x` fits into `al`. If you want to support larger values of `x` and `y`, you should convert your `x` to a 16-bit type before multiplying the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `imul r/m8` will produce result in `ax` not `dx:ax`. If you intend to use the 16 bit multiply, you should make sure to put the operand into a 16 bit register.

As for the subtraction, sounds like you want to synthesize a 32 bit one. That's easily done by `SUB` and `SBB` to account for carry.

As such, the code could look like:

```
movsx cx, y
mov ax, cx
imul cx
imul cx
mov low_y, ax; save low y^3 (dw)
mov high_y, dx; save high y^3 (dw)
movsx cx, x
mov ax, cx
imul cx
imul cx
mov low_x, ax; save low x^3 (dw)
mov high_x, dx; save high x^3 (dw)
sub ax, low_y
sbb dx, high_y
```

Note that I have swapped order since it's more convenient to calculate `x^3-y^3` if you calculate `y^3` first.

You can subsequently check whether the result fits into your signed byte.

Comment: thank you first.
i just didn't understand something...
you did low_x - low_y
and then high_x - low_x (sbb)
so now i'm also need to do high_x - high_y right?

Comment: That's because I messed that up, the last one should of course be `high_x (which is in dx at  that point) - high_y`.